# Asp.Net Refresh Token "invalid_grant" when created manually

Tags: asp.net, owin

I'm generating an access token in ASP.NET from an endpoint that receives a googleIdToken(GoogleAuth). The access token is generated successfully and works fine, I can use it to make requests to my API with no issues. The problem comes when I try to generate a refresh token from that same endpoint; I can see that the refresh token is added to the DB, but when I try to get a new access token using the refresh token it returns "invalid_grant".

Debugging I found that the *GrantRefreshToken* method in my *ApplicationOAuthProvider* is not executed after retrieving the refresh token.

Here's how I create both the access and refresh tokens:

**My Endpoint:**

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GenerateEHSTokenFromGAuth(ExternalSignInRequest request){
                //gets user info from google
                var tokenInfo = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(request.TokenId);

                //Some logic to match google user to my users table.

                // Generate AuthTicket
                var oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(_userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                var formData = GetRequestInfo(request);
                var ticket = await _authService.CreateAuthTicket(oAuthIdentity, formData);
                var token = _authService.CreateToken(ticket);

                var cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(_userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);

                //Create refresh token
                Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context =
                    new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(),
                        Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);

                await Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenProvider.CreateAsync(context);
                var refreshToken = context.Token;

                var accessTokenExpiration = ((DateTimeOffset)ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc).Subtract((DateTimeOffset)ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc).TotalSeconds;

                ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
                ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("access_token", token);
                ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("expires_in", accessTokenExpiration.ToString());
                ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Add("token_type", "bearer");

                context.SerializeTicket();

                return Ok(ticket.Properties.Dictionary);
        }
```

**RefreshTokenProvider:**

```
public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
        {
            var username = context.Ticket.Identity.Name;
            var unit = (IUnitOfWork)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
            var refreshTokenLifeTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RefreshLifetimeMinutes"];
            var aspnetRefreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var data = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
            var userName = context.Ticket.Identity.Name;

            var token = new AspNetRefreshToken()
            {
                AspNetRefreshTokenId = aspnetRefreshTokenId,
                UserName = userName,
                IssuedTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeviceSource = GetDeviceSource(),
                ExpiredTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(refreshTokenLifeTime))
            };

            token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

            //Remove old refresh tokens
            var tokensToRemove = unit.AspNetRefreshTokenRepository.Get()
                .Where(x => (x.DeviceSource == deviceSource || x.DeviceSource == null) && x.UserName == userName || x.ExpiredTime < DateTime.UtcNow);

            foreach (var tokenToRemove in tokensToRemove)
                unit.AspNetRefreshTokenRepository.Remove(tokenToRemove.AspNetRefreshTokenId);

            unit.AspNetRefreshTokenRepository.Add(token);
            context.SetToken(aspnetRefreshTokenId.ToString());
            unit.Save();
        }
```

And this is the method that gets called when I try to get an access token using the refresh token. I can see that the token is retrieved from the DB, but after this method is executed the execution ends and I get the invalid_grant message.

```
public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {
            var unit = (IUnitOfWork)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
            var data = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
            var deviceSource = data.Get("device_source");

            Guid tokenId = Guid.Empty;
            var validGuid = Guid.TryParse(context.Token, out tokenId);

            if (!validGuid)
                return;

            var token = unit.AspNetRefreshTokenRepository.Get()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AspNetRefreshTokenId == tokenId && x.DeviceSource == deviceSource);

            if (token == null)
                return;

            context.DeserializeTicket(token.ProtectedTicket);
            unit.AspNetRefreshTokenRepository.Remove(new Guid(context.Token));
            unit.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that I was creating the context with the wrong TokenFomat. If you need to create a context for a refresh token you need to give that context a RefreshTokenFormat.

So instead of

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context =
                new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(),
                    Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat, ticket);
```

Do:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context =
                new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext(),
                    Startup.OAuthOptions.RefreshTokenFormat, ticket);
```

And that will execute the *GrantRefreshToken* where you create your new access token.